# Quickblox "Bad Timestamp" error while Creating session IOS

Tags: ios, session, timestamp, quickblox

While creating session in Quickblox i am getting error.

The same code is working in one iPhone 5 device and in other iPhone 5 device it is giving error.

```
Bad Timestamp
```

Then i noticed that on one device the date and time option was not set to Automatic. When i changed to Automatic then it worked.

But i am stuck what should be the solution whether i have choose Date and time Automatic or not.

I am using below code to initialise Quickblox Framework

```
[QBSettings setApplicationID:];
[QBSettings setAuthKey:@""];
[QBSettings setAuthSecret:];
[QBSettings setAccountKey:];
[QBSettings setAutoReconnectEnabled:YES];
```

I have set the above keys and have removed them from above code.

Answer (score 0):

Your device time shouldn't differ from server more then 2 hours.

Comment: What if some users have set their time wrong. So how can we fix in this case?

Comment: Make an understandable error, which will guide users to fix their local time.

Comment: But how these apps like Whatsapp work in similiar condition?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/21555253

Why is the timestamp on my received messages / last seen incorrect?
If the timestamp displayed on your received messages or the last seen time of your friends are incorrect, review the time and time zone configured on your phone. It is likely that one or both need to be changed.

We recommend setting your date and time to Automatic or Network Provided. With this setting enabled, your mobile provider will set your phone to the correct time. If the incorrect time is displayed even with this setting enabled, this is an issue with your network. Please contact your mobile provider to address the issue.
As a workaround, please modify your date and time settings and correct your time zone manually.
Note: The time zone is different than the actual time. Make sure the correct time zone for your location is selected.
To configure your time zone manually, please follow these steps for your phone:

Comment: What are these steps?